# Show new content on gatsby website when Prismic CMS content is updated

Tags: gatsby

I'm planning to make a website with Gatsby and Prismic. On one page I will be sourcing content from Prismic, this content may change daily (new blog etc.). Is it possible to have gatsby get this new content without having to manually build the website each time?

Comment: https://medium.com/source-group/start-a-new-website-with-gatsby-prismic-cms-netlify-a875455c992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to avoid a rebuild, but it is possible to avoid a *manual* rebuild.

You can trigger a rebuild of your site whenever the content in Prismic changes. If you're using Netlify, check out this section in the [Gatsby Prismic tutorial that @ksav provided above](https://medium.com/source-group/start-a-new-website-with-gatsby-prismic-cms-netlify-a875455c992).

> On the Netlify dashboard, go to the section “Build hooks” in “Build & deploy” and create a hook, then copy and paste the URL.
> Now, go to Prismic in “Webhooks” in the settings page and paste the URL build hook from Netlify. After saving, test it by clicking on the button “Trigger it”.